# ошибка при обработке датасета(.jsonl) для дообучения gpt3 через APIopenai

Tags: python, json, dataset

проблема происходит при попытке загрузки датасета для дообучения

в датасете такие данные(это лишь маленький фрагмент, но с той же структурой):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "question": "Q:What really makes you angry?->",
      "answer": "I'm not emotional, but many people can get angry at injustice, violations of their rights, ignorance and aggression###"
    },
    {
      "question": "Q:Who is your hero?->",
      "answer": "My hero is someone who shows courage and compassion in all situations###"
    },
    {
      "question": "What is your opinion on the potential dangers of artificial intelligence?",
      "answer": "While I acknowledge the potential dangers, I believe that with proper regulation and oversight, we can create AI that benefits humanity without causing harm."
    },
    {
      "question": "What is your favorite robot?",
      "answer": "I really admire the design of Boston Dynamics' robots, especially the agility of the Spot robot."
    }
  ]
}
```

Код:

```
import openai
import json

openai.api_key = "*мой API ключ(тут убрал)"

# Загрузка датасета из файла JSON Lines
with open('D:/GPT3/dataset.jsonl', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    dataset = [json.loads(line) for line in f] #ошибка тут

# Настройка параметров дообучения
model_engine = "davinci"  # движок GPT-3, на котором будет происходить дообучение
temperature = 0.7  # температура генерации текста
max_tokens = 1500  # максимальное количество токенов для генерации текста
learning_rate = 0.02  # скорость обучения
batch_size = 1  # размер пакета данных для обучения
epochs = 5  # количество эпох дообучения

# Начало дообучения модели
for item in dataset:
    prompt = item['question']
    completion = item['answer']
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine=model_engine,
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens=max_tokens,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        temperature=temperature,
    )

    new_text = response.choices[0].text.strip()
    new_prompt_completion = prompt + new_text + "###"

    response = openai.FineTune.create(
        model=model_engine,
        data=new_prompt_completion,
        batch_size=batch_size,
    )

    print("Response:", response)
    # сохранение ID модели в файл
    with open("model_id.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(response["model"])
```

ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\GPT3\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    dataset = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
  File "D:\GPT3\main.py", line 8, in <listcomp>
    dataset = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

Comment: А openai каким боком в этом вопросе? Ищите ошибку в 'dataset.jsonl', приведенном вами фрагменте этой ошибки нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас файл не в формате JSONL. В JSONL все вложенные JSON должны быть отформатированы в одну строку, а разделителем между JSON должны быть переносы строк.

И хоть я файн-тюнингом не занимался, что-то мне подсказывает, что эндпойнт ожидает от вас полный файл JSONL, а не отдельные JSON.